# How can I add more stairs to the specific group of stairs without changing its position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairs: MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Stairs Prefb")]
    public GameObject stairsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Platforms")]
    public bool addPlatforms = false;
    public GameObject platformsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Settings")]
    [Range(0,5)]
    public float delay = 3;
    [Range(5,100)]
    public int stairsNumber = 5;
    public Vector3 stairsStartPosition;
    public Vector3 stairSize;
    public Vector3 stairsSize;
    public float stepWidthFactor = 1f;

    private Vector3 stairsPosition;
    private int oldStairsNumber;
    private MoveStairs moveObjects;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        oldStairsNumber = stairsNumber;
        moveObjects = gameObject.GetComponent<MoveStairs>();
        StartCoroutine(BuildStairs(moveObjects));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(oldStairsNumber < stairsNumber)
        {
            AddStairs();
        }

        oldStairsNumber = stairsNumber;
    }

    private IEnumerator BuildStairs(MoveStairs moveObjects)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= stairsNumber; i++)
        {
            stairsPosition = new Vector3(
                    stairsStartPosition.x,
                    stairsStartPosition.y + (i * stairsSize.y),
                    stairsStartPosition.z + (i * stairsSize.y) * stepWidthFactor);

            stairsPosition = stairsPosition + transform.localPosition;

            GameObject stair = Instantiate(
                    stairsPrefab,
                    stairsPosition,
                    Quaternion.identity);

            stair.name = "Stair";
            stair.tag = "Stair";
            stair.transform.parent = transform;
            stair.transform.localScale = stairSize;

            moveObjects.objectsToMove.Add(stair);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }

        moveObjects.enabled = true;
        moveObjects.Init();
    }

    private void AddStairs()
    {
        for (int i = oldStairsNumber; i < stairsNumber; i++)
        {
            stairsPosition = new Vector3(
                stairsStartPosition.x,
            stairsStartPosition.y + (i * stairsSize.y),
            stairsStartPosition.z + (i * stairsSize.y) * stepWidthFactor);

            stairsPosition = stairsPosition + transform.localPosition;

            GameObject stair = Instantiate(
                    stairsPrefab,
                    stairsPosition,
                    Quaternion.identity);

            stair.name = "Stair";
            stair.tag = "Stair";
            stair.transform.parent = transform;
            stair.transform.localScale = stairSize;

            //moveObjects.objectsToMove.Add(stair);
            //moveObjects.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm not using the two lines `moveObjects.objectsToMove.Add(stair);` and `moveObjects.Init();` it will add the stairs but the new added stairs will be static. But if I will use this two lines the new added stairs will also move but it will also change the whole stairs position.

This is a screenshot when not using this two lines after added new stairs:

[image: Stairs static]

And this screenshot when using the two lines after added new stairs:

[image: Stairs moving]

Now the stairs are moving but not in the same position the stairs was before.
The stairs now are moving much faster then the others.
And there is no gap's spaces between the stairs like there was before. Gaps I mean on Stairs 0 like in the first screenshot.

This is the MoveStairs script that move the stairs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveStairs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToMove = new List<GameObject>();
    public AnimationCurve curve;
    public float stepsPerSecond = 1f;
    public bool changeDirection = false;

    private Vector3 trackStart;
    private Vector3 trackEnd;
    private Vector3 horizontalTravel;
    private float verticalTravel;
    private float divisor;
    private float phase = 0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Init()
    {
        if (curve == null)
        {
            curve = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(0, 0), new Keyframe(1, 1));
        }
        curve.preWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;
        curve.postWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;

        trackStart = objectsToMove[0].transform.localPosition;
        int count = objectsToMove.Count;
        var span = objectsToMove[count - 1].transform.localPosition - trackStart;

        divisor = 1f / count;
        horizontalTravel = (count + 1) * span * divisor;
        horizontalTravel.y = 0f;

        verticalTravel = span.y;
        trackEnd = trackStart + (count + 1) * span / count;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (objectsToMove != null && objectsToMove.Count > 0 && curve != null)
        {
            AnimationCurve();
        }
    }

    private void AnimationCurve()
    {
        phase = Mathf.Repeat(phase + stepsPerSecond * divisor * Time.deltaTime, 1f);

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            float t = Mathf.Repeat(phase + i * divisor, 1f);
            // Get the height of the curve at this step.
            float curveHeight = curve.Evaluate(t) * verticalTravel;

            if (changeDirection)
            {
                objectsToMove[i].transform.localPosition = trackStart                // First step
                                  - horizontalTravel * t      // evenly spaced horizontal
                                  + curveHeight * Vector3.up; // curving vertical
            }
            else
            {
                objectsToMove[i].transform.localPosition = trackStart                // First step
                                  + horizontalTravel * t      // evenly spaced horizontal
                                  + curveHeight * Vector3.up; // curving vertical
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main goal is when the game is running in real time when changing the stairs number value: Up or Down add/destroy new stairs for the specific group of stairs.

```
public int stairsNumber = 5;
```

The last script is the first one is creating each Stairs Unit like Stairs 0 Stairs 1 Stairs 2 each Unit is a duplication of a prefab that have attached the two scripts above the GenerateStairs and the MoveStairs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairsUnits : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Stairs Units Prefab")]
    public GameObject stairsUnitsPrefab;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Settings")]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfUnits = 1;
    [Range(10, 100)]
    public int gap = 10;

    private int oldNumberOfUnits = 0;
    private List<GameObject> units = new List<GameObject>();
    private GameObject unitsParent;
    private GameObject Unit;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        oldNumberOfUnits = numberOfUnits;

        unitsParent = GameObject.Find("Stairs Units");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
        {
            Unit = Instantiate(stairsUnitsPrefab, unitsParent.transform);
            Unit.transform.localPosition = (i + 1f) * new Vector3(gap, 0, 0);
            Unit.name = "Stairs " + i.ToString();
            Unit.tag = "Unit";
            units.Add(Unit);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: create two sockets on each stair , one at top and and one at , create a prefab , and keep adding or deleting using a list .

Comment: @LumbusterTick Could please give some example how to do it ?

Comment: create one set of stair , after that create two empty game objects , one at top and one at bottom of that stair , turn it into a prefab . Now if you want to add another stair on top of previous one add it to the location of the empty game object of the first one .If you want to add below then add it to the location of the bottom empty object. Keep references in a list so you can add and delete .Ofcourse youll have to figure out the snapping by some offset but it will be easier as the empty gameobjects will provide location top and below

Comment: the offset for each new stair will given by empty game objects which will be same for each stair in local space

Comment: @LumbusterTick Sorry but I forgot to mention the first script the GenerateStairsUnits I edited my question and added the script. I'm duplicating a prefab that hvae already attached the two scripts above the GenerateStairs and MoveStairs so I can control also each Stairs Unit individual for example changing the amount of stairs only or Stairs 0. So I'm not sure how to make a prefab from each Stair like Stairs 0 and how to add the empty objects as sockets. If I have in MoveStairs the List objectsToMove how should I update this List ?

Comment: Btw your duplicate prefabs should not have those scripts . As for your question "how should I update this List ? " . You are using moveObjects.objectsToMove.Add(stair); <---- does this not work ?

Comment: @LumbusterTick Yes I messed up all the 3 scripts. Making Add(stair) working for update but messing up the resto f the stairs in the group. Still I can't figure out how to make a simple add/remove stairs from a specific group(Unit).

Comment: If you want specifics , create a dictionary with key value pairs , that way you know exactly which one to delete and add